# Issue with scrolling text in CSS

Tags: html, css

I tried to attempt scrolling text using css3 transitions, it looks all good to me but does not appear to work for some reason. Would really appreciate some help. Thanks in advance.

```
.scrollingtext {  
 height: 200px;   
 overflow: hidden;  
 position: relative;  
}

.scrollingtext h1 {  
 position: absolute;  
 width: 100%;  
 height: 100%;  
 margin: 0;  
 line-height: 50px;  
 text-align: center;  
-moz-transform:translateY(-100%);  
-webkit-transform:translateY(-100%);      
 transform:translateY(-100%);  
-moz-animation: scrollingtext 15s linear infinite;  
-webkit-animation: scrollingtext 15s linear infinite;  
 animation: scrollingtext 15s linear infinite;  
}  


@-moz-keyframes scrollingtext {  
0%   { -moz-transform: translateY(-100%); }  
100% { -moz-transform: translateY(100%); }  
}
@-webkit-keyframes scrollingtext {  
0%   { -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%); }  
100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(100%); }  
}  
@keyframes scrollingtext {  
0%     {     
-moz-transform: translateY(-100%);  
-webkit-transform: translateY(-100%  );   
 transform: translateY(-100%);      



 }  
 100% {   
 -moz-transform: translateY(100%);   
 -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);   
 transform: translateY(100%);   
 }  
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v656vx5o/2/

Comment: Because Your element's class is `.scrolltext` no `.scrollingtext`. Change `.scrollingtext h1` to `.scrolltext h1` in Your CSS

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/oLfmmz8e/ working fiddle

Answer (score 1):

You call wrong class in your html `scrolltext`

```
<div class="scrolltext">
  <h1 align="center" div id="h11">text</h1>
</div>
```

should be:

```
<div class="scrollingtext">
  <h1 align="center" div id="h11">text</h1>
</div>
```